# How to replace the last char of a string in bash with another char

Tags: bash

I have strings which represent versions (always in the following format):

```
1.0.0
1.1.0
1.5.0
20.189.0
456874.0.0
```

The last part of the string will always be `.0`.
Now I'm searching for a way in bash how I can replace this with `.X`

```
1.0.X
1.1.X
9.5.X
20.189.X
...
```

Comment: `"${str%.0}.X"`

Comment: `sed 's/0$/X/g' `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sed -i 's/.$/X/' filename`

It will replace last char by `X` in each line, rewrite file `filename`.

Answer (score 10):

very simple approach would be

```
str=testString
echo ${str%?}X
```

it just select string without last character and appends X as a trailing character

Answer (score 9):

Using `bash` manipulation:

```
str='1.0.0'

echo "${str/%.0/.X}"
1.0.X
```

or else:

```
echo "${str%.0}.X"
1.0.X
```

Answer (score 3):

##### Replacing last number in IP address with 1

```
$ hostname -i | sed 's/.$/1/'
```

##### Replacing 't' with 'z'

```
$ echo "xyt" | sed 's/.$/z/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we have bash, we can also use the super-simple "index to the last char and replace it, e.g.

```
str=1.0.0
```

To index to the last char you use `${str:0:$((${#str}-1))}` (which is just `str:0:to_last-1`) so to replace the last character, you just add the new last character at the end, e.g.

```
$ str=1.0.0
$ echo ${str:0:$((${#str}-1))}X
1.0.X
```

There are always multiple ways to skin-the-cat in bash.

(personally, I'd use the *parameter expansion with substring removal* -- but those were already taken...)

Comment: You do not need to count. Instead use only `${str:0:(-1)}`.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are in file `file`:

```
$ cat file
1.0.0
456874.0.0
1.1.666
```

(notice the last one above)

```
$ for s in $(cat file) ; do echo ${s%.*}.X ; done
1.0.X
456874.0.X
1.1.X
```